# Yii framework: get the resultant html from a view in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, yii

This is a peculiar situation but I have a simple .php view in an yii application that displays some html based on the parameters passed to it. I'm calling it like this:

```
echo $this->renderPartial('/comments/view', array('comment'=>$comment));
```

I'm doing this several times as the page might have more than one comment in it.

This works fine, however, once someone posts a new comment, I want to dynamically display it on the page without reloading it. So here come AJAX doing its magic and calling a refresh function after its done which needs to refresh the content of the div displaying the comments:

```
    function refreshComments()
    {
        var content = $('#users_posts').html();
        var newContent = "<?php $this->renderPartial('/comments/view', array('comment'=>Comments::getLatestComment($model->id))); ?>";
        $('#users_posts').html(newContent + content);
    }
```

Obviously the part where I'm trying to stuff the variable newContent with the needed html fails. This part works with no problem:

```
Comments::getLatestComment($model->id)
```

As I'm able to get the information from the newly inserted comment in the database. The problem is displaying in on the screen as I have to wrap it up with plenty of html which also depends on the values returned by the getLatestComment. The view is doing this just fine, however, how can I get the result from it and stuff it into the JavaScript variable so I can properly update the HTML of the div?

Or and other suggestions in that manner are more than welcome as well!

Comment: There are many things that you are doing wrong with your code. Also regarding the Ajax implementation, use the JSON to send the data to the view and use a library such as Jquery/Mootools to append the data into the view. Check out @parry's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few ways to achieve what you are trying to do.

First method would be to correct your existing code like following :-

CommentsController :-

```
public function actionGetLatestComments($id){ //$id variable is the ID of the latest comment on the page
    if(isset($_POST['post_id'])){
        $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
        $post = Post::model()->findByPk($post_id);
        if($post){
            //check for any new comments here using the $id variable passed
            //echo out all the HTML of new comment(s) here
        }
    }
}
```

User's view side :-

This side you need to keep track of all the comments you have under your post like for ex.

```
<div id='users_posts'>
    <div id='2'>
        ...comment with ID 2...
    </div>
    <div id='1'>
        ...comment with ID 1...
    </div>
</div>
```

Supposing your latest comment to be the first comment in the comment's list, you can fetch it's ID by the following JS :-

```
$('#users_post div').first().attr('id');
```

Use this ID inside the JS function refreshComments() like this :-

```
function refreshComments(){
    var id = $('#users_post div').last().attr('id');
    $.post('/comments/getLatestComments/'+id, {post_id:POST_ID_HERE}, function(data){
        $('#users_posts').append(data);
    });
}
```

Using this method will increase the toll on your server as your server will be returning the whole HTML again and again if there is a new comment available.

Or you can use JSON data to reduce the over head from each request like this :-

CommentsController :-

```
//inside the getLatestComments function
echo CJSON::encode(array(/* here array of new comments if available */));
```

On the user's view side :-

```
//inside refreshComments function 
var id = $('#users_post div').first().attr('id');
$.post('/comments/getLatestComments/'+id, {post_id:POST_ID_HERE}, function(data){
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(data, function(id, value){
        $('#users_post').append("<div id='"+value.id+"'>"+value.comment+"</div>");
    });
});
```

This way you can use JSON to fetch all the latest comments and make it more efficient.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Perfect answer!! Exactly what I would have given as well!! +1